# using interval partitioning in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to learn `MYSQL` with the knowledge I learn from `Microsoft Sql` and `Oracle`. I'm trying to use interval partitioning on a table but I'm not seeing the solution for the error I'm having.

```
create table telmar_php.call_log
(
 log_id int not null,
 sender int,
 reciever varchar(30) not null,
 call_duration TIMESTAMP,
 call_start TIMESTAMP,
 call_end TIMESTAMP,
 primary key (log_id),
 foreign key(sender) references number_assigned(sender)
)
partition by RANGE (call_duration) //This is the error line
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'HOUR')) 
(PARTITION "2015-03-15 00:00:00" VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('2015-03-16 00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')));
```

that's the code is that you can't use interval partitioning in MYSQL?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: I believe OP is gettng this error...Error Code: 1492. For RANGE partitions each partition must be defined...His syntax is not correct

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_interval_partitioning.htm) will allow you to partitions using intervals, such as:

`create table 
pos_data ( 
   start_date        DATE,
   store_id          NUMBER,
   inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
   qty_sold          NUMBER(3)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
(

   PARTITION pos_data_p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
);`

However, if you want to partition in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html) you have to explicitly define each one, like below:

`CREATE TABLE tblemployeepunch (
      fld_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      fld_date Varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_rawpunchdate varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_rawpunchtime varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_cardno varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_reasoncard varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_mode varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_punchdatetime varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      fld_crtdate  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      UNIQUE KEY fld_id (fld_id,fld_crtdate),
      KEY in_timesheet (fld_cardno,fld_punchdatetime,fld_mode,fld_rawpunchtime),
      KEY in_emppunch (fld_cardno,fld_rawpunchdate,fld_punchdatetime)
    )
     PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fld_crtdate))
     (PARTITION p_Sep12 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-01 00:00:00')),
     PARTITION p_Oct12 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-01 00:00:00')),
     PARTITION p_Nov12 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-12-01 00:00:00')),
     PARTITION p_Max VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Oracle, MySQL does not support interval partitioning. You have to explicitly define each partition.